# How to display a long text file whiptail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, whiptail

This is the code than open a whiptail message box based on the content of the file in the file variable. The file has many lines.

```
$(whiptail --title "Opening file" --yesno "$(cat $file)" 78 78 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

Now the box is fixed in width and height.
How to show a scrolling text box so I can see all of the text in the file?

Comment: We face the same issue on Debian since Stretch. The scroll bar is actually added, but only visible below the text. Try to create a dialog with fixed height but only a very short single line text. Then the scroll bar shows up below the text line. However, of course a scroll bar has no point if the text is too short to have anything to scoll: https://github.com/MichaIng/DietPi/issues/2947, https://bugs.debian.org/945320

Answer (score 1):

The option `--scrolltext` is supposed to do this, and reading source code, it applies to *textbox* and *messagebox* (*yesno* is a special case of the latter), but in a quick check, I see no scrollbar.  Perhaps it will work with the version of newt which you are using.